# Transposition $(a\ b)$ with $\gcd(b-a,n) =1$ and cycle $(12\dots n)$ generate $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Prove that if $1≤a<b≤n$ with $\gcd(b−a,n)=1$, then the transposition $(a\ b)$ and the cycle $(1 2…n)$ generate $S_n$.

Comment: Since $(a,b)^{(1,2,\ldots,n)^{(n-a)}} = (n,b-a)$, an equivalent phrasing would be: Let $m\in\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$. Prove that $(m,n),(1,2,\ldots,n)$ generate $S_n$.

Comment: The following also interests me: if $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=d$, which subgroup of $S_n$ would $(m,n),(1,2,\ldots,n)$ generate?

Comment: @YACP, I didn't mean to imply I had a solution. Still thinking about it, but I certainly won't object if anyone else can point us in the right direction.

Comment: @YACP I notice you have tagged many of your questions with the commutative algebra tag. Surely it serves the same purpose as group theory!

Answer (score 2):

Building on my comment, we let $1<m<n$ be coprime, and take $(m,n),(1,2,…,n)\in S_n$. Note that
$$(m,n)(1,2,…,n) = (1,2,\ldots,m-1,n)(m,m+1,\ldots,n-1).$$

Now, since $m,n-m$ are also coprime, taking $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $rm+s(n-m)=1$ we have
$$\sigma:=\left((m,n)(1,2,…,n)\right)^{rm} = (1,2,\ldots,m-1,n)^{rm}(m,m+1,\ldots,n-1)^{1-s(n-m)} = (m,m+1,\ldots,n-1),$$
and similarly
$$\tau:=\left((m,n)(1,2,…,n)\right)^{s(n-m)} = (1,2,\ldots,m-1,n).$$

For all $a\in\{m,m+1,\ldots,n-1\},b\in\{1,2,\ldots,m-1,n\}$, we then have
$$(m,n)^{\sigma^{a-m}\tau^{b\pmod n}} = (a,b),$$
and for all $a_1,a_2\in\{m,m+1,\ldots,n-1\},b_1,b_2\in\{1,2,\ldots,m-1,n\}$ we have
$$(a_1,n)^{(a_2,n)}=(a_1,a_2);\quad (b_1,m)^{(b_2,m)}=(b_1,b_2),$$
thus generating every transposition (and therefore every permutation) in $S_n$.

The case of $m=1$ is more easily handled: $(1,n)(1,2,…,n)=(1,2,…,n-1)$, so by conjugation we can get any transposition $(k,n)$, and therefore any other transposition as well.

As this question is of real interest to me, I'd appreciate feedback in case I made some silly mistake. As an aside, I'm still interested in the question I posed above: if $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$, which subgroup of $S_n$ would $(m,n),(1,2,…,n)$ generate?

Comment: Oh, I'm never sure about these web scripts. Anyhow, may I ask, since you've introduced the current conditions, regarding the origins of the question? Have you seen it raised/solved somewhere before? Regarding the math itself, we use $\gcd(b-a,n)=1$ to formulate the question in the way I preferred to attack it, i.e. with coprime $0<m<n$, since $(a,b)^{(1,2,\ldots,n)^{(n-a)}} = (n,b-a)$ and $(n,b-a)^{(1,2,\ldots,n)^{a}} = (a,b)$. We then used $m,n$ being coprime (and hence, $m,n-m$ being so) to generate $\sigma,\tau$, which have disjoint sets of fixed points.

Comment: Yes, of course. $\tau^k$ is the group multiplicative power, and $\sigma^\tau$ stands for the conjugate $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$.

Comment: @YACP, I know that's not the way to get attention for my questions. I wasn't aiming at that; I just thought this construction might be familiar to someone who'd come along shortly, in which case I needn't spend any time on it. As it is, asking a question before spending any real time working on it isn't how I want to handle this.